# How statistics or record the consumption of each request CPU and memory in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want to record every request the consumption of resources such as CPU and memory, is used to check a problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to measure memory consumption, but CPU consumption can be measured.

You need to:

- Set thread affinity of the managed thread on which you process the request, to the OS thread. This can be done with `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity` - don't forget to pair it with `Thread.EndThreadAffinity` at the end of the request.
- PInvoke `QueryThreadCycleTime` from Windows API, which queries current thread CPU cycles. Do it at the beginning of the request and at the end, then get the difference between the two.
- Optonally, you can also translate CPU cycles to time, by PInvok'ing `QueryPerformanceFrequency` and doing the right math.

I attach the complete code of a helper class as a Gist at https://gist.github.com/felix-b/7cda7d4f44d05e66874b4b2dad4fd3d2#file-threadcputimeutility (I had trouble pasting the code here, it gets distorted for some reason).

Since there are plenty of ways you can hook your code into begin and end of a request (beware that ASP.NET pipeline is not entirely executed on the same thread - let me know if you need further help on that). For now I'll just focus on what needs to be done.

In the request start:

```
 Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();
 _startCpuCycles = ThreadCpuTimeUtility.GetTheadCycles();
```

In the request end (must run on the same thread with the code above):

```
 var endCpuCycles = ThreadCpuTimeUtility.GetTheadCycles();
 Thread.EndThreadAffinity();

 var cpuMicroseconds = ThreadCpuTimeUtility.GetThreadCpuMicroseconds(
     _startCpuCycles, 
     endCpuCycles);
```